# Debugging a multi-thread programe with "Disassembly view" in visual studio

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, assembly

[image]

When I continuously do "step into",it switches between different threads.

But how's that scheduled in visual studio,how does it know which thread to activate for next instruction?

Comment: You're a sockpuppet for COMer, aren't you?  I know the answer, you know what to do to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not up to Visual Studio which thread runs next, it's up to the Windows scheduler. There's usually a way to "freeze" the other threads in the process so that they won't run while you're trying to look at a particular thread, though I don't know how to do it in Visual Studio.

-scott

Comment: right-click, freeze. You can do that on multiple selected threads too.